# cancan: is it possible to create an alias for more than one action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

My ability model contains 8 roles. I'd like to use aliases to help simplify the content. Can an alias contain more than one action, e.g.

```
alias_action :action1, action2, :to => :basic_access
```

Also, is this the correct placement of the alias?

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability
alias_action :action1, action2, :to => :basic_access

def initialize(user)
    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: @skorks, care to take a shot at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the wiki:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Action-Aliases

1. Yes, `alias_action` can be called with more than one action.
2. It looks like you need to move your `alias_action` call into `initialize`.